# Linking to a site that offers more learning on a language?

Tags: support, answers, advertising

I answer quite a few questions in some demographics, and I currently run a screencasting site, which does topical Python screencasts weekly.

Would it be out of line to share a link to those who are interested in my answers to people who ask question?

If that isn't appropriate where could I do such linking?

Comment: This sounds like people may believe it's spam; you're posting links for solely promotional purposes.

You could add it to your profile or change your username

Comment: Sounds like something you should be putting in your profile, rather than including in posts.

Comment: thats interesting that they would find it spammy, if they are interested in learning wouldn't that be useful addition to the answer, of course if its relevant.

Comment: You should update your "about me" section. I certainly wouldn't have imagined that there was anything programming-related by seeing just that domain name.

Comment: @Mat I literally just did that a few moments ago.

Answer (score 5):

If the links are relevant to the **answer** and post, they are OK, so long as you disclose your connection to the linked site.

But, from your description, this isn't the case - the site is for *general* information, so as such this would be self promotion that isn't merited by the answer.

In general - you should be wary of self promotion on Stack Overflow - with relevance and self disclosure, as there are parts of the community that frown on any kind of self promotion, even such that is actually helpful and relevant.

Comment: It may be self promotion, but if its topical and relevant to the question being asked why would they frown upon it, because my motivation might be slightly more motivated than boosting a reputation number?

Comment: @garbagecollector - I am talking about observed behavior. Some people don't care if it is topical and relevant (and fully disclosed). They just flag as spam.

Comment: is that something we want to continue as a community? Is this a good practice? What can we do about this perception?

Comment: @garbagecollector - Those are all good questions, worthy of their own posts.