# Community flagging questions with links as spam

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I just asked this question and some of the answers I received were quite interesting.

For those of you interested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197176/linking-to-a-site-that-offers-more-learning-on-a-language) is the question.

Now the generally feeling got from this question which asks is it wrong to link to things that I have done outside the site (screencasts) in this case that a topical and on point with the question being asked.

The answers and comments I got were

> I am talking about observed behavior. Some people don't care if it is
>   topical and relevant (and fully disclosed). They just flag as spam
>
> In general - you should be wary of self promotion on Stack Overflow -
>   with relevance and self disclosure, as there are part of the community
>   that frown on any kind of self promotion, even such that is actually
>   helpful and relevant

Then I posed the following questions.

> It may be self promotion, but if its topical and relevant to the
>   question being asked why would they frown upon it, because my
>   motivation might be slightly more motivated than boosting a reputation
>   number?

and most of all.

> Is that something we want to continue as a community; limiting a
>   better answered question so stifle self promotion? Is this a good
>   practice? What can we do about this perception?

I would be really interested in people thoughts.

Comment: As per the answer to the linked question, if the resource you provide is on topic for the question being asked and adds value to that question, rather than just being a general resource, it wouldn't be a violation of the rules.  It would be spam if you were including it when it's not strongly related to the question at hand.

Comment: Related: [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers) and [Defining the limits of self-promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion) and [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182212/what-signifies-good-self-promotion-or-self-promotion-part-infinity)

Comment: Also related: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) and [How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022)

Answer (score 6):

The general guidelines for self-promotion are:

1. If your main purpose in using Stack Overflow is to promote your own materials, rather than to ask/answer questions, you shouldn't be doing this.
2. You must always disclose your affiliation with the promoted materials clearly within the text of the question/answer.
3. If the self-promotion is directly relevant to the answer, does help the OP accomplish their task, is *rarely what you point to*, and you have a body of other high-quality answers not relating to your self-promotion, then it's probably okay.

So ask yourself these questions and then determine what applies to you in this case!